# Building Proxy Site with Nginx and Rotating Proxy Service

Tags: nginx, networking, proxy, nginx-config, http-proxy

Im' looking to build a similar application to https://www.proxysite.com/  but am not sure on the best architecture.

Looking to have a data flow like this.

User Web Browser ->  myproxysite.com ->  Ngninx Proxy Server (somehow rotating IP for each client session)  ->   Targetsite.com

Then the user would need to maintain a full session on Targetsite.com as a logged in user.

In this example,  targetsite.com is always the same site and is pre-determined.  The challenge we are facing is that targetsite.com  is blocking our users based on IP,  many of whom are accessing it from the same office network.

So my questions are:

1. Does this seem correct?
2. Is there anyway for me to configure nginx with a rotating proxy service like luminati?  Or do I need to add an API software layer to handle the actual IP changes?

Any guidance on this one would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While I can't help you with your application, I do want to suggest an alternative. You mentioned an office so it sounds like the users who will use the proxy are workers.

Luminati (now BrightData) has a proxy manager which you can host on any server. The proxy manager allows you to create ports (ie port 24000) and configure it with whatever proxy you want (doesn't have to be BrightData's proxy). It has a ton of different parameters that you can include for each proxy (including IP rotation) and each port can be configured to have a unique setup.

Then you simply go to your user PC, open the browser proxy settings, type the IP address of the server that the proxy manager is running on and the specific port you configured and voila. You have central control of the managing the proxies and your user's browser is proxied.

A big benefit of this is the logs in the proxy manager show all activity on each port you setup, so you can monitor traffic and the success rates right there.

Proxy manager: https://prnt.sc/13uyjgj

Comment: hey there, i really appreciate this reply.  It may be better than nothing, so I'll look into it!  Cheers